# Angular - building various versions

Tags: angular, git, jenkins, npm

I have one Angular project that has many branches, but let's say that there are two, `master` and `feature`. `master` uses `Angular 12` and `feature` uses `Angular 14`. Both branches are active, that is there is development done on both. If I am on one of them and switch to the other, I can't build this project without additional actions, because `npm` - while building - complaints about unresolved dependencies. The only way that *I* to make it work is to run:

```bash
rm -f package-lock.json
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
npm run buildprod
```

My question is: is there any other, faster way (in terms of build time) to do it? This is not a real issue when building locally because I can delete once and then only `npm run buildprod`, but our Jenkins has some hard time with it, because it must (?) do it every time it is asked to build the project.

Note that I am not asking about Jenkins - in reality situation is much more complicated and we don't want to fight Jenkins unless we absolutely have to.

Comment: I would approach this by having two separate clone directories, one for each required version of Angular. Install in each clone with the corresponding dependencies. When you need one or the other, cd into the right clone.

Comment: But my higher-level question would be: does Jenkins really need to build both? Can it not build only the version it needs for the commit that just got pushed? You could have conditionals in your workflow that install only the relevant version for the build in progress.

Comment: Two directories are certainly some solutions, but not an ideal one, especially since we have custom scripts that deal with multiple repositories (and if we want to go many people advocate, that is single repo, this will be even worse) and we'd have to rewrite it in some parts - I'll check it.

Comment: And about Jenkins - I don't quite understand part "Can it not build only the version it needs for the commit that just got pushed". It builds what was pushed, but without checking what version is being built (12 or 14) we have to clean build tree, which is exactly what I want to avoid. I think what I wanted to ask is "Can npm somehow detect different versions by itself and reinstall required modules". I don't think this is the case, but who knows.